# Not able to add margins on buttons through code

Tags: android, button, row, margin

Here is my code, I am trying to add few buttons in a row. Its working fine, But these buttons appear too close to each other, I want to apply horizontal margins to buttons. But not able to add. To achieve this I tried to keep button inside a Linearlayout and applied margins to it. But it somehow don't show any buttons, And when I comment out this line- `ll.setLayoutParams(lp);` Buttons can be seen again, But without any margin. Please let me know how can I make buttons at some distance from each other.

```
maintable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
//ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
Button b = new Button(savedLists.this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
params.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 20);
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circular);
b.setText(Integer.toString(c));
b.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
ll.addView(b,params);
tr.addView(ll);
c++;
}
maintable.addView(tr);
```

R.drawable.circular is just creating a simple circular button. Please let me know, if I should post that too.

Comment: You haven't set any margin for the button here. You are setting it's padding!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set any margin for the button here. You are setting it's padding! Here is how you can set the margin for a button!

```
Button b = new Button(context); 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height); 
params.setMargins(top, left, bottom, right);
yourLinearLayout.addView(b,params);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jordan for reply, But its still not working. I have updated code in my question as per your your suggestion, Please recheck and help.